# ClassTag not available error when the type were not annotated as such?

Tags: scala, types

Given the following dual-typed class `KVO`(with `ClassTag`) and `T` (with none):

```
class P2pRDD[KVO:ClassTag,T](sc: SparkContext, parent: RDD[KVO])
extends RDD[T](parent) {
```

The code is not compiling due to:

```
Error:(28, 11) No ClassTag available for T
  extends RDD[T](parent) {
      ^
```

But why would a ClassTag be *required* for `T` .. given the absence of any such requirement in the declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the necessity were driven by the usage of `RDD[T]` . The RDD expects an array type and needs the `T` `ClassTag` to deduce the type of the array parameters. Therefore we do need `ClassTag` on *both* type parameters:

```
class P2pRDD[KVO:ClassTag,T: ClassTag](sc: SparkContext, parent: RDD[KVO])
extends RDD[T](parent) {
```